# How do I sort an objects array by id and name?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an objects array by `id` and `name`.

Sample data:

```
 [
 {
      "case": {
        "name": "Exemple1"
      },
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "case": {
        "name": "Exemple1"
      },
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "case": {
        "name": "Exemple2"
      },
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "case": {
        "name": "Exemple3"
      },
      "id": 4
    },
    {
      "case": {
        "name": "Exemple2"
      },
      "id": 6
    }
  ]
```

I want to sort by `id` and the `name` field in the `case` object ? Is it possible to use two criteria in sort?

Expected result:

```
 [
    {
      "case": {
        "name": "Exemple1"
      },
      "id": 2
    },
        {
      "case": {
        "name": "Exemple1"
      },
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "case": {
        "name": "Exemple2"
      },
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "case": {
        "name": "Exemple2"
      },
      "id": 6
    },
    {
      "case": {
        "name": "Exemple3"
      },
      "id": 4
    }
 ]
```

How can I use two criteria in my sort?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - sorting array by multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560801/javascript-sorting-array-by-multiple-criteria), [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields), [Javascript array sorting based on multiple criteria (in one iteration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61857654/javascript-array-sorting-based-on-multiple-criteria-in-one-iteration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure it's possible.

The [`Array#sort` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) takes an optional parameter called [`compareFunction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description) that represents the logic to perform when sorting any two items in the array.

By passing a function that compares first by `case.name` then by `id`, you can sort your array by both criteria. Here's a simple example, though you'll likely want to add error checking so you don't try [reading an `undefined` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property).

```js
const unsortedData =  [
  { "case": { "name": "Exemple1" }, "id": 3 },
  { "case": { "name": "Exemple1" }, "id": 2 },
  { "case": { "name": "Exemple2" }, "id": 1 },
  { "case": { "name": "Exemple3" }, "id": 4 },
  { "case": { "name": "Exemple2" }, "id": 6 }
];

const sortedData = unsortedData.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.case.name > b.case.name) return 1;
  if (a.case.name < b.case.name) return -1;
  if (a.id > b.id) return 1;
  if (a.id < b.id) return -1;
  return 0;
});

console.dir(sortedData);
```

Comment: @D M, thank you for your help, It's work and i can use this exemple for a better understanding, and use for other sort.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#sort` with custom comparator. You can use conditional OR to compare on multiple condition.

```
arr.sort((a,b) => a.case.name.localeCompare(b.case.name) || a.id - b.id)
```

```js
const arr = [{ "case": { "name": "Exemple1" }, "id": 3 }, { "case": { "name": "Exemple1" }, "id": 2 }, { "case": { "name": "Exemple2" }, "id": 1 }, { "case": { "name": "Exemple3" }, "id": 4 }, { "case": { "name": "Exemple2" }, "id": 6 } ];
arr.sort((a,b) => a.case.name.localeCompare(b.case.name) || a.id - b.id);
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```